# NoMethodError when running RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am getting the error NoMethodError when trying to use RSpec for testing the gem I created.

this is my gem:
*~/project/gemz/spec/lib/checksomething.rb*

```
class Checkpercentage

  #1) what is  x% of y?
  def self.findAmount(rate, base)
    resultAmount = rate * base/100
    return resultAmount
  end 

  #2) x is what percentage of y?
  def self.findPercent(amount, base)
    resultPercent = amount/base * 100
    return resultPercent
  end

  #3) x is y% of what number?
  def self.findBase(amount, rate)
    resultBase = amount/rate *100
    return resultBase
  end

end # End Module
```

And this is my rspec test file:
./project/gemz/spec/lib/checkpercentage_spc.rb

```
require "spec_helper"
require "checksomething"

RSpec.describe Checkpercentage, '#intNum' do
  context "with no integer entered" do
    it "must be a number" do
      checkpercentage = Checkpercentage.new
      checkpercentage.findPercent(100, 200)
      expect(checkpercentage.intNum) > 0
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test if the values enterend in the findPercentage method are > 0. However, when I run the rspec command in my terminal (*rspec spec/lib/checkpercentage_spc.rb*) the following error comes up:

```
Failures:

1) Checkpercentage#intNum with no integer entered must be a number
   Failure/Error: checkpercentage.findPercent(100, 200)
   NoMethodError: undefined method `findPercent' for #<Checkpercentage:0x9956ca4>
   # ./spec/lib/checkpercentage_spc.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00089 seconds (files took 0.17697 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
    rspec ./spec/lib/checkpercentage_spc.rb:6 # Checkpercentage#intNum with no integer entered must be a number
```

I'm fairly new at ruby on rails. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Santhosh I am already doing that on the previous line by assigning the class into a variable 'checkpercentage': -- checkpercentage = Checkpercentage.new -- checkpercentage.findPercent(100, 200)

Comment: Class methods can only be called on the class constant.
When you are creating an object the methods you defined aren't available as it is an `instance` you are talking to and not a `class` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. As Santhosh wrote, the way you have declared your methods (using `self`) makes all of them methods for  the `Class` (`Checkpercentage`) itself. If you want them to be called on `instance` (`Checkpercentage.new`) you have to remove `self` from the declaration.
2. What is `intNum` (looks like Java but it doesn't exist in Ruby)? If I understand correct you want to check that `findPercent(amount, base)` returns a positive number. In that case, [the right RSpec syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/built-in-matchers/comparison-matchers) is `expect(checkpercentage.findPercent(100, 200)).to be > 0`.
3. In `Ruby` a) `camelCase` is avoided in favour of `camel_case` and b) methods return the result of the last line that was executed. These mean you can rewrite your code as follows:

   ```
   class Checkpercentage

     #1) what is  x% of y?
     def find_amount(rate, base)
       rate * base/100
     end 

     #2) x is what percentage of y?
     def find_percent(amount, base)
       amount/base * 100
     end

     #3) x is y% of what number?
     def find_base(amount, rate)
       amount/rate * 100
     end

   end # end Module
   ```

*notice that I have removed the `self` keywords to show you what I meant with my first point - now the syntax in the test you have written (`checkpercentage.method_name`) will be correct*

**Notice, furthermore, that there is a bug in your code - it works but not as you want it too. Hopefully the tests you'll write will help you find it and fix it, if not let us know!**

Comment: Yes, with the tests I can see that something is not right with my code but I'm still struggling to find exactly what. I'll keep trying though, thanks for the help again :)

Comment: @VictorAngelo Anytime, my pleasure! In order to find the mistake, try to have a very simple test, something like `expect(checkpercentage.find_percent(100, 200)).to equal(0.5)` for example. This should tell you what you expected and what you got and you can move from there.